# MongoDB find user not in array

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm currently developing a multiplayer card game with a node.js + mongodb backend. I want users to be able to join games so I'm implementing a queue function. In this queue function I want to be able to get a single game from mongodb that is not started, not locked and doesn't contain the player in the queue.

Example of my mongodb game document:

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "512cccf9e4b09000a6f1f079"
},
"mChanceTaken": false,
"mCurrentPlayer": 0,
"mCurrentPlayerName": "-",
"mDeck": [
    {
        "mValue": 13,
        "mSuit": "HEARTS"
    },
    {
        "mValue": 13,
        "mSuit": "SPADES"
    },
    {
        "mValue": 3,
        "mSuit": "SPADES"
    },
    {
        "mValue": 10,
        "mSuit": "SPADES"
    },
    {
        "mValue": 11,
        "mSuit": "CLUBS"
    },
    {
        "mValue": 3,
        "mSuit": "HEARTS"
    },
    {
        "mValue": 7,
        "mSuit": "DIAMONDS"
    },
    {
        "mValue": 9,
        "mSuit": "SPADES"
    },
    {
        "mValue": 8,
        "mSuit": "HEARTS"
    }
],
"mFinished": false,
"mLocked": false,
"mNumberOfPlayers": 4,
"mPlayers": [
    {
        "mPlayerId": "512bd9a1e4b09000a6f1f073",
        "mUsername": "user2",
        "mPosition": 0,
        "mSwitching": true,
        "mFaceUp": [],
        "mFaceDown": [],
        "mHand": []
    },
    {
        "mPlayerId": "512bcb3be4b09000a6f1f06b",
        "mUsername": "user1",
        "mPosition": 0,
        "mSwitching": true,
        "mFaceUp": [],
        "mFaceDown": [],
        "mHand": []
    }
],
"mRoundLength": 60,
"mStarted": false,
"mSwitching": false
```

}

My current query looks like this:

```
GameBoard.findOneAndUpdate({mStarted: false, mLocked: false, mPlayers: {$not: {mPlayerId: player.mPlayerId}}}, {mLocked: true}, function (err, gameBoard) {
```

I think I should use the $not operator but I can not figure out how to use it in  my use case. please someone help me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the [$ne](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/ne/) operator since [$not](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/not/) is only used in conjunction with another operator expression.

Comment: I tried to do : GameBoard.findOneAndUpdate({mStarted: false, mLocked: false, mPlayers: {mPlayerId: {$ne: player.mPlayerId}}}, {mLocked: true}, function (err, gameBoard)  and I tried GameBoard.findOneAndUpdate({mStarted: false, mLocked: false, mPlayers: {$ne: {mPlayerId: player.mPlayerId}}}, {mLocked: true}, function (err, gameBoard) { but none of them works like I want. The first always give me  no game and the second always give me a game. How would you write it?

Comment: I think `{mStarted: false, mLocked: false, mPlayers.mPlayerId: {$ne: player.mPlayerId}}` should work.

Comment: It doesn't work, MongoDB/node is no big fan of "mPlayers.mPlayerId" and gives me unexpected token on the dot =/

Comment: `{mStarted: false, mLocked: false, "mPlayers.mPlayerId": {$ne: player.mPlayerId}}` maybe? I am just familiar with the Java driver so I have to guess (and google) what is the problem here, sorry. :)

Comment: doesn't seem to work, I get no game hits =/ I'll just have to try some more stuff. but thanks for your help!

Comment: I tested the query in the shell and it is definitely working this way. Could you replace `player.mPlayerId` with a constant value (e.g. "xyz") and tell us the result? On a related note: Your update query should probably look like this `{$set: {mLocked: true}}`.

Comment: Will try to replace that in a bit. Regarsding the update, from what I have read in the driver api my update will be executed like that even though I wrote it differently. But could you please explain the difference? Or is it just syntax error to do it like I do?

Comment: [Update](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/update/) replaces the existing document (except the _id field) if you do not use it with an additional [update operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/update/#crud-update-operators). The [$set](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/set/) operator for example updates/adds just a particular value in your existing document.

Comment: Now I feel pretty silly.. I accidentaly changed started to true on the game in my database.. so the solution with "mPlayers.mPlayerId" did work! Thank you very much for your help!